# VB6 Compile error for NewItem Variable Definition

Tags: vb6

```
Dim value As New ValueItem
```

Showing Compile Error:

> User defined type not defined.

I am using VB6.

The code used to work fine a month back but after I ran it yesterday the error keeps showing.
I found other questions where they suggest that I should change the Binary Compatibility etc. But in my project properties the Compatibility page is grey out. Tried all other options but no help. Any idea about what steps I can take to resolve this issue.

Comment: VBA ? VB6?  Which one? In vba Most of the User defined type error are the reference setting.

Comment: in VBA it's better to do it in two steps : `dim value as ValueItem` and `set value as new ValueItem` because the dim stay a declaration of a variable and not an instantiation

Comment: @MaximePorté Then you will have code with different meaning. `Dim value As New ValueItem` declares a variable that will never be `Nothing` - if it's Nothing and you're accessing it, it will be instantiated automatically. `Dim value As ValueItem` only declares the storage, and if it's Nothing when you access it, you'll get an exception.

Comment: @Soham Check your project's references. If nothing is missing, then apparently you lost a source code file where `ValueItem` was defined.

Comment: @Omar sorry for the confusion. It is in VB6.

Comment: @ GSerg I have used the same code a month back and it was working fine. But now it shows the error. All the original files are there since I did not replace or delete anything from the project in the past month.

Comment: Can you give the declaration of ValueItem?